How can I change my repository path for chrome driver to work on IntelliJ?
Please how can I solve this;How to solve the problem Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\meaghanlewis\Downloads\chromedriver
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at KeyboardAndMouseInput.main(KeyboardAndMouseInput.java:11)
I have tried changing the path but it’s not working. Please any solution ?
I tried changing the path but each time I run the code it keeps saying the driver does not exist

This question is similar to: Java Selenium Chromedriver.exe Does not Exist IllegalStateException. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
